# Famous parametric curves that are solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parametric

I know that the cycloid satisfies the differential equation

$ \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 - \frac{2r}{y}  + 1 = 0. $

Are there other famous plane curves that are also solutions to a differential equation?  I guess what I'm really asking is whether there is an easy way to find the differential equation given a parametric equation.

Comment: You might also look at the famous curves index on the St.Andrews history of maths site http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Curves/Curves.html

Comment: There's also the tractrix, the catenary, and the pursuit curve.